# Convert my type to expected argument type

Tags: swift, xcode, apollo

I'm using Apollo Client to autogenerate graphql types and queries in Xcode but have run into an issue I'm not sure how to best solve. TLDR is how can I allow one struct to be used as an argument for a function that accepts another type with the same structure?

Apollo generates a struct for me called "SizeInput" as follows:

```swift
struct SizeInput: GraphQLMapConvertible {
  public var graphQLMap: GraphQLMap
  public init(cm: Double) {
    graphQLMap = ["cm": cm]
  }
  public var cm: Double {
    get {
      return graphQLMap["cm"] as! Double
    }
    set {
      graphQLMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "cm")
    }
  }
}
```

(BTW - `GraphQLMap` is a typealias for `[String : JSONEncodable?]`)

I created a `Size` struct for use in my code. I don't want to use the `SizeInput` in my code to keep the back-end separate from my app code so things don't break if the back-end or app changes.

```swift
struct Size {
  let cm: Double
}
```

I need to run an apollo query that takes `SizeInput` as an argument, which I want to populate from my `Size` variable populated from a picker. While I know I can create a new `SizeInput` from `Size`, I'd love to just pass `Size` into the query because they're essentially the same, just two different types. As of now, XCode obviously complains `Cannot convert value of type 'Size' to expected argument type 'SizeInput'`

The kicker is that I can't (don't want to) change the Apollo function because that's autogenerated. So my ideal solution is to typecast `Size` to `SizeInput` in some fashion, but XCode complains if I just try to do `let sizeInput = size as? SizeInput` where `size` is a `Size`.

Assuming I can't modify the function accepting the argument and I can't modify `SizeInput` because both are autogenerated, how can I modify `Size` so it can be used as a `SizeInput` argument?

Comment: Can you extend `struct Size` with a function that returns the `SizeInput` type that you need and then call that function at the call-site where you need a `SizeInput` ?

Comment: I can if that ends up being the best solution. I was hoping for a clean way to be able to use `Size` as a `SizeInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Size` and `SizeInput` according to your post are two different types and therefore can't be type aliased in the manner you are thinking.

[Swift's Declarations reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html) says the following about `typealias`:

> A type alias declaration introduces a named alias of an **existing type** into your program. [...] After a type alias is declared, the aliased name can be used instead of the existing type everywhere in your program. [...] Type aliases do not create new types; they simply allow a name to refer to an existing type.

... but that's not what you want. `Size` and `SizeInput` are similar contractually in that they have a `cm: Double` property, but are structurally different under the hood and can't be used interchangeably.

You're going to need to make some trade-offs with whatever solution you choose. I see at least the following options.

- You can write a layer that sits on top of your codegen GraphQL stuff that provides the interface you want (i.e. takes a `Size`) and use that. Then translate your `Size` to `SizeInput`. Codegen could be used.
- You could provide some sort of type-level function of `Size` to `SizeInput` on the `Size` type itself and then use that at your GraphQL call-sites. Codegen could be used here too.

```
extension Size {
   func asSizeInput() -> SizeInput {
        return SizeInput(cm: cm)
    }
}
```

- You could also at the call-site into your GraphQL just pass your `Size` instance's `cm` property into the constructor of `SizeInput`, then you're not writing any extra code. Here's some pseudo code:

```
let size = Size(cm: 100)
let query = SizeInputGraphQLQuery(sizeInput: size.cm)
```

For my $, I'd opt for writing as little extra code as possible.

YMMV

Comment: That's what I suspected but wanted to confirm. Thanks!